# TreeSet Java Code working in java application but not in android project

Tags: android, date, treeset

This is my code when i doing as java application

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;


import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class DateRounding {

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {


List ls=new ArrayList();

ls.add (new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm", Locale.ENGLISH).parse("2010-02-31-14-30"));
ls.add(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm", Locale.ENGLISH).parse("2010-02-31-14-50"));
ls.add(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm", Locale.ENGLISH).parse("2010-02-31-14-10"));
ls.add(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm", Locale.ENGLISH).parse("2010-02-31-14-01"));
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
String string = "2010-02-31-14-00";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(string);
Date x=getDateNearest(ls , date);
System.out.println("date:"+x);
System.out.println(ls.indexOf(x));
System.out.println("index:"+ls.indexOf(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm", Locale.ENGLISH).parse("2010-02-31-14-10")));


}




private static Date getDateNearest(List<Date> dates, Date targetDate){
    return new TreeSet<Date>(dates).higher(targetDate);

         // return targetDate;

    }

}
```

when i add same code to android project is showing error "The method higher(Date) is undefined for the type TreeSet" ,but this higher() is working perfectly in java application.....how can i use higher method in android?

Comment: You should implement the getDateNearest() method differently, maybe with an iterator and compare the dates by yourself, it will probably solve your problem, and test it on an android device/amulator.

Comment: @Meh is right - it's horribly inefficient to create a new treeset just to use the higher function and discard the set, and lazy list programming. Implement a sort and search yourself, it'll be much more efficient - which is key on Android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compliance settings of your compiler are set to JRE 1.4 (`higher` first appeared in 1.5). Check the configuration of your project (difficult to give details without even knowing which tool or IDE it is).

Recent versions of Android not just support but even require compliance with JRE 1.5 or 1.6. From that I can quickly test, Android 2.2 API level 8 complains and Android 3.1 level 12 already do not. As of today, the most recent level is 17.

Check the [developer manual](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html) on how to build the right application for Android. `public static void main(String[] args)` is not the right way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Leaving aside the arguments in the comments, if you **really** want to use .higher(), then you must set min API level of 9 or higher.